# select all rows from sql server db with for loops in c#.net and set to datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I have two forms with name `Sale` and `Sale return`
`sale` form is working fine, but I have an issue with `sale return` form.

I want to get all rows in `datagridview` from `Sale Database` with `for loop`, but when I run given below select query, only one row has select.

So please help me for resolve the this issue.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace DataGridViewtoTextbox
 {
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Random rand = new Random();
        DataGridView dgv = this.dataGridView1;

        //DATAGRIDVIEW SETTING
        dgv.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        dgv.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        dgv.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect;

        //ADD COLUMN HEADERS
        dgv.Columns.Add("Invoice", "SInvoice");
        dgv.Columns.Add("Code", "ItemCode");
        dgv.Columns.Add("Amount", "Price");
        dgv.Columns.Add("Quantity", "Quantity");

        //ADD 10 ROWS


        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=mateenwin; User ID=sa; Password=123");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Sale_Invoice_No,Item_Code,Item_Payable_Amount from sale where Sale_Invoice_No = '" + textBox1.Text + "'", con);

        SqlDataReader sdr;
        sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (sdr.Read())
        {

            int itm = (Int32)sdr["Sale_Invoice_No"];
            int inovice = (Int32)sdr["Item_Code"];
            double ptype = (double)sdr["Item_Payable_Amount"];
            int qnty = (Int32)0;
            ////NOW, POPULATE THE DATA INTO THE CELLS
            int n = dgv.Rows.Add(sdr);


            for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = itm;
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = itm;
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = ptype;
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = qnty;

                con.Close();

             }
        }


        //int inv =Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sale_Invoice", "Sale_Invoice"));
        //int cod=Convert.ToInt32( cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item_Code", "Item_Code"));
        //double amount=Convert.ToDouble( cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item_Payable_Amount", "Item_Payable_Amount"));
        //cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        ////NOW, POPULATE THE DATA INTO THE CELLS
        //for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        //{
        //    double price = rand.Next(1, 30) * rand.NextDouble();

        //    dgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = inv;
        //    dgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = cod;
        //    dgv.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = amount;
        //    dgv.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = 0;
        //}

        //CLEARS THE DEFAULT SELECTION WHICH IS THE FIRST ROW
        dgv.ClearSelection();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
        int cod = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value);
        double price = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value);
        dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value =Convert.ToDouble( (cod) * (price));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I think it should be while(sdr.read)

Comment: this is responding an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." so please help in for loope

Comment: Could you point out which line have this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=mateenwin; User ID=sa; Password=123");
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("Select Sale_Invoice_No as Invoice, Item_Code as Code, Item_Payable_Amount as Amount, 0.00 as Quantity from sale where Sale_Invoice_No = '{0}'", textBox1.Text), con);
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet dsInvoices = new DataSet();
sda.Fill(dsInvoices);

dgv.DataSource = null;
dgv.DataSource = dsInvoices.Tables.Count > 0 ? dsInvoices.Tables[0] : null;
```

Comment: this is responding an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." so please help in for loope

Comment: int cod = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value);

Comment: this error is coming in dataGridView1_CellValueChanged event

Comment: Check null before convert it into `Int32`

Comment: with your query datagridview columns datatype has change as per database columns so i want to datagridview columns datatype manualy which help me for CellCaluechanged event

Comment: `int cod = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value);`

Comment: Same issue on form load

Comment: Need to check null for `double price = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value);` also same as I mentioned in previous comment.

Comment: same issue is found please help me in for loops which have not such issue

Comment: Change the select query as `Select Sale_Invoice_No as Invoice, Item_Code as Code, Item_Payable_Amount as Amount, 0.00 as Quantity from sale where Sale_Invoice_No = '{0}'`

Answer (score 0):

If its not essential to insert data using a for loop you can get the data to a Dataset and bind it with the grid as follows.

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string txt=textBox1.Text;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds=db.getDataQuery(txt);

    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
}
```

Query to get the data

```
public DataSet getDataQuery(string txt)
{
   try
   {
        String strQuery = @"Select Sale_Invoice_No, Item_Code, Item_Payable_Amount from sale where Sale_Invoice_No = '" + txt + "'";

            return SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(your_connection_string_name, CommandType.Text, strQuery);
   }

  catch (Exception ex)
  {
     throw ex;
  }
```

}

Please edit the answer according to yours. You have to make a connection string. Try to create connections globaly. It's good habbit.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are closing connection to database inside for loop.so it is expected that after processing first row connection will be closed.
Also reader need to advanced for next row until it has row.
Also you need to put proper check on reader before using it.

Please check my code here and use it.

```
do
{
        if (sdr.HasRows)
        {


        int itm = (Int32)sdr["Sale_Invoice_No"];
        int inovice = (Int32)sdr["Item_Code"];
        double ptype = (double)sdr["Item_Payable_Amount"];
        int qnty = (Int32)0;
        ////NOW, POPULATE THE DATA INTO THE CELLS
        int n = dgv.Rows.Add(sdr);


        for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = itm;
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = itm;
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = ptype;
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = qnty;


         }

        }
} while (sdr.NextResult());

con.Close();
```